# I can't get arrested in Whiterun

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, when I get arrested in Whiterun, the loading screen won't load and I have to restart my game. Is it because I killed the guards in the jail? I need help! Could I get arrested in another Imperial town, and then would they stop trying to arrest me in Whiterun?

Comment: From what I understand, the holds track bounties independently. This means that you can't, for example, get arrested in Riften due to crimes committed in Whiterun. However, you may be able to get arrested in a different town in Whiterun (e.g. Rorikstead or Riverwood), although they may try to ship you off to the jail in Whiterun, I don't know -- never been arrested myself.

Comment: You could use a bounty hunter to pay off your fine in Whiterun, and then just not commit any more crimes there.

Answer (score 2):

What you do is when they try to arrest you walk backwards and repeatedly put your weapon away and then draw it.

The reason why this works is because your temporarily surrendering  so they stop arresting you and you can pay it off

Note that this only works with bounties at 350 gold or less so if its above that then you need to be able to say "I'm with the guild".

Incase you didn't know you get that dialogue by joining the thieves guild